# programmatically accessing compiled CSS class names in angular 2

Tags: d3.js, angular

In d3, I make a lot of elements like this:

```
this.title = svg.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'graph-title')
    .text('blah blah blah');
```

I was hoping I could put that class in the CSS local to the component creating this svg, but you can't refer to the local css this way.  What I did above would only work if I put the relevant style into the global CSS, which for reusability reasons is not what I'd like to do.

Is there some way I can programmatically add the local css class to this dynamically-created element?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What is the local component? What do you want to achieve by mixing this classes? Maybe there is a workaround for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `>>>` (or `/deep/`) to address dynamically added elements that don't get the encspsulation attributes (`_ng_content...`) added from styles added to components:

```
:host >>> graph-title {
  ...
}
```